# Programmatically create Applications and Services

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

For our new project we have to support a multi-tenant scenario. It has been recommended that having an application per tenant is the safest model, so we have logically separated our Apps into **SystemApps** and **TenantApps**

Where the tenant services should be accessible (internally) via

**fabric:/TenantApps_{tenantId}/SomeTenantSvc**

We intend to have a System service that creates and removes client applications and checks their health. These applications will have a default service which in turn starts/stops other services within their application based upon their subscriptions.

All good in theory, but I can't for the life of me find where to create new applications and services from code.  I Assume it's something to do with the FabricRuntime - but the finer details elude me.

If anyone is able to give an example or link to the correct documentation then I would be grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Here's](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-deploy-remove-applications-fabricclient) the documentation.

This is how to do create an application instance in code, using an existing application type:

```
string appName = "fabric:/MyApplication";
string appType = "MyApplicationType";
string appVersion = "1.0.0";

var fabricClient = new FabricClient();

//  Create the application instance.
try
{
   ApplicationDescription appDesc = new ApplicationDescription(new Uri(appName), appType, appVersion);
   await fabricClient.ApplicationManager.CreateApplicationAsync(appDesc);
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{
}
```

And for services:

```
// Create the stateless service description.  For stateful services, use a StatefulServiceDescription object.
StatelessServiceDescription serviceDescription = new StatelessServiceDescription();
serviceDescription.ApplicationName = new Uri(appName);
serviceDescription.InstanceCount = 1;
serviceDescription.PartitionSchemeDescription = new SingletonPartitionSchemeDescription();
serviceDescription.ServiceName = new Uri(serviceName);
serviceDescription.ServiceTypeName = serviceType;

// Create the service instance.  If the service is declared as a default service in the ApplicationManifest.xml,
// the service instance is already running and this call will fail.
try
{
   await fabricClient.ServiceManager.CreateServiceAsync(serviceDescription);
}
catch (AggregateException ae)
{}
```

Comment: typical as soon as I post I find a similar example, I'll try this first, thanks LoekD!