# Create new instances of service fabric app dynamically when an instance is already running

Tags: azure-service-fabric

Is creation of another instance of the service fabric app (programatically) supported, when an instance is already running?

I want to create new instances of the same service fabric app based on the demand, programatically. Not sure if its allowed to create new instances when an instance is already running.

Thanks!

Comment: [Yes][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/43719762/5946937

Comment: Yes, I tried that. I get "Application already exists" error.

Comment: I guess I can give it different app name. But that would require rebuild of the app, not sure how it can be done dynamically/programatically. What I am really looking for is update the 'Instance Count' of an app dynamically.

Comment: Never mind, looks like app name can be set at run time via name field in ApplicationDescription .